# How do we get Indices for glDrawElements()?

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

I'm trying to use the Assimp library to import models to a rudimentary OpenGL application with VBO use.

If I understand it correctly glDrawElements is one of the ideal modern ways to draw things.

But how do we get that information from a generic import library?

If you have specific Assimp library knowledge it's appreciated.

--

What is generally the process to generate these?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Collect all indices from `aiMesh::mFaces` in a single buffer. Make sure to pass `aiProcess_Triangulate` to Assimp as postprocessing flag (amongst `aiProcess_JoinVertices` and whatever seems useful to you), and skip over points and lines or handle them separately.

The various data streams in `aiMesh` - such as `aiMesh::mVertices` and `aiMesh::mNormals` need to be set as GL input data streams (`glVertexPointer`, ...).

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/data.html) it looks like the `aiFace::mIndices` from an `aiMesh::mFaces` index into `aiMesh::mVertices`.

`aiVector3D` looks like it's laid out such that you should be able to able to just call `glVertexPointer()` with `mVertices` and use `mIndices` directly in your `glDrawElements()` call.